# Uncaught Loaded unexpected element while trying to get rendering HTML from server. Expecting last tag to be closing script marker - Angular JSS

Tags: jss

"Uncaught Loaded unexpected element while trying to get rendering HTML from server. Expecting last tag to be closing script marker" in Sitecore Angular JSS version 10.1

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have got this error in Sitecore Angular JSS version 10.1 when the component gets added in Experience editor mode.

Following are the reasons for the error to occur:

- Without null check for rendering property value and when it's getting to bind empty property.
- When the rendering(HTML) is having a comment section with a conditional statement sometimes breaks in HTML.

`<!--<ng-template #elseStatement> Unused Logic </ng-template>  -->`

Solution:

- Always add null check even if the field is required in Sitecore.
- Remove unwanted commented lines from HTML.